# How to divide COCO dataset evenly?

Tags: python, json

I have full COCO dataset I downloaded from [here](https://cocodataset.org/). I need to modify the `instances_train2017.json` file a bit to get following:

- modify the annotations file, so it divides the full train dataset into `1/3` for all classes evenly
- means let say I have 100 images/annotations for `class_1`, so I want my modified annotations file to hold the `100/3` of image objects/dict in json file

I have written code like this, but it takes too much time and result/modified file is wrong:

```py
import json
from collections import defaultdict
import random
# Path to your local COCO-format JSON annotation file
original_annotation_file = 'coco/annotations/instances_train2017.json'
output_annotation_file = 'evenly.json'
# Load the local COCO-format dataset from your JSON file
with open(original_annotation_file, 'r') as f:
    coco_data = json.load(f)

class_counts = defaultdict(int)
target_class_counts = defaultdict(int)

# Calculate the target count for each class
for ann in coco_data['annotations']:
    class_id = ann['category_id']
    class_counts[class_id] += 1

for class_id, count in class_counts.items():
    target_class_counts[class_id] = count // 3

# Create a list to hold the selected annotations
selected_annotations = []

# Iterate through the annotations and select the subset
for ann in coco_data['annotations']:
    class_id = ann['category_id']

    # Only include this annotation if we haven't reached the target count for this class
    if class_counts[class_id] <= target_class_counts[class_id]:
        selected_annotations.append(ann)

        # Update the count for this class
        class_counts[class_id] += 1

# Create a new COCO-format JSON data structure for the subset
subset_data = {
    'info': coco_data['info'],
    'licenses': coco_data['licenses'],
    'categories': coco_data['categories'],
    'images': coco_data['images'],
    'annotations': selected_annotations
}

# Shuffle the selected annotations to mix up the classes if desired
random.shuffle(subset_data['annotations'])

# Write the subset data to a new JSON file
with open(output_annotation_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(subset_data, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you decrease the `target_class_counts[class_id]` after you appended the instance to your `selected_annotations` it would fix your problem. so replace the code below it should fix your problem.

```
# Only include this annotation if we haven't reached the target count for this class
if target_class_counts[class_id] > 1:
    selected_annotations.append(ann)

    # Update the count for this class
    target_class_counts[class_id] -= 1
```

But still would be slow. I suggest creating a dictionary of lists where the key is the `category_id` and the value is the `annotations` data labeled as that key

```
data = defaultdict(list)
for ann in coco_data["annotation"]:
    class_id = ann["category_id"]
    data[class_id].append(ann)
```

Now you can iterate through `data` and shuffle each list and then use slicing to get what ever portion of the data you wan't.

Comment: I'm still not sure if it divides the data by 1/3 for all classes though.

Comment: It will give you first 1/3 of each class.